# angular-material app - ng-mouseover on md-menu-bar

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a problem with `md-menu-bar` directive. I have a bar with a button (hamburger) and with a title. I would like to show this bar only on `mouseover`. But when viewed normally, it should be not visible.

So only when cursor is in the correct place (top of the page)...and additionally it should be a smooth transition that makes it slides down, what should I do? I've tried `ng-show`, `ng-hide` and `ng-style` or `ng-class` to change this but it doesn't work. Please help.

```html
<md-menu-bar layout="row" id="toolbar" class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-menu>
        <button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">
            <md-icon md-svg-icon="icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
        </button>
        <md-menu-content>
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button ng-click="ctrl.windowAction('settings', $event)">Settings</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-divider></md-menu-divider>
            <md-menu-item>
                <md-button ng-click="ctrl.windowAction('calendar', $event)">Calendar</md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
    <h2 id="title">Home Page</h2>
</md-menu-bar>
```

This is how the menubar currently looks like:
[image: Screenshot]